# Swift Playgrounds: Rendering Local html file in WebKit works on simulator but not on device

Tags: swift, webkit, swift-playground

I'm trying to render a WebKit view using a local HTML file i have on my playground but it renders it on the simulator but it doesn't on the playground.

My code looks something like this:

```swift
import UIKit
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
import WebKit

public class Plastic : UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    public override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "plastic", withExtension: "html")!
        webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

    @objc func notification(){
        PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = Banana()
    }

}
```

Can this be a bug in playgrounds for local HTML files not to be rendered? This is odd behaviour for me and I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Art of the Bodge. This is one way i fixed it to work on a device. Not the best way but it does the job in the short time I had.

```swift
if let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "pla", ofType: "html"){
            do{
                let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: url)
                webView.loadHTMLString(contents, baseURL: nil)
            } catch {
                return
            }

        }
```